# How to load Rails Session from session_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store` in my application to store Sessions in the database.  It all works fine.  However, I'd like to be able to load a specific Session when passed the `session_id`.  This is the value that the server stores as a cookie on the client side.

My Rails application has a client that can't use cookies, so it has to pass me the `session_id` in a parameter.  I'd like to use a `before_action` or some sort of filter to take that parameter and use it to load the `session` in my Controllers instead of the app loading a null session due to the lack of proper cookies.

Is there some way I can do this?  I don't want to turn off the cookie method altogether because my web client uses cookies, it's just my mobile client that can't.

edit:
if I declare `class Session < ActiveRecord::Base` and then do `Session.find_by_session_id('whatever')` I do get a Session ActiveRecord object, but I'm not sure how to make this into a usable `session` in the normal Rails sense.

Comment: Solved:  Just do request.session_options[:id] = "whatever you want" in a `before_action` filter and Rails will use that session_id to load the Session when you access it (thanks to lazy loading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do request.session_options[:id] = "whatever you want" in a before_action filter and Rails will use that session_id to load the Session when you access it (thanks to lazy loading).